# MySQL, copying tables files gives rise to "ERROR 1017 (HY000): Can't find file:" even though its there there

Tags: mysql

I want to copy the database tables from my production server to a local test machine so I can perform test om (copies of) the real data.

I stopped mysql and deleted all the frm, MYD and MYI files. Starting mysql here and querying show tables gives an empty result set. I then shut down mysql and copied all the frm, MYD and MYI files from the server. When starting mysql "show tables" shows the tables as expected but trying to query them I get the error message

> ERROR 1017 (HY000): Can't find file: './WhateverTableIQuery.frm'
>   (errno: 13)

But the WhateverTableIQuery.frm file is on the disc and is identical to the one on the server.

Any ideas about what might be the problem?

Comment: I didn't dump and import because I wanted to save time. Some of the tables are big and building the indices takes forever.

Answer (score 35, accepted):

I'd suggest giving two things a try:

**1. Check Permissions**

Make sure that your MySQL data directory and all the files in it are owned by mysql user and mysql group. This may not be the case if you copied the files onto your local test machine as root user:

```
chown -R mysql:mysql your-mysql-data-dir-here
```

**2. Repair corrupted tables**

Use [mysqlcheck](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/mysqlcheck.html) to check for corrupted tables and repair them if it finds any:

```
mysqlcheck -u root -p --auto-repair --all-databases
```

If you still can't use the tables after that then give mysqldump a go!

Comment: As you guessed I copied the files as root and forgot to change the owner. Doing so fixed the problem. Thanks a lot!

Comment: Hmmm. `sudo ls -lah /var/lib/mysql/homestead` already says that all of the tables files are owned by the `mysql` user and group. And `mysqlcheck -u root -p homestead` didn't find any problems. So unfortunately I'm still lost.

Answer (score 3):

I encountered the same issue after restoring a MySQL database with frm and MYD files. After a number of hours spent I observed that I have configured the database directory with only read and write permission to mysql user but not execute permission. After adding execute permission to the database directory, the problem was solved.

Answer (score 0):

I did have the very same issue a couple minutes ago and it took me a few minutes to realize that I had insufficient permission to access the .sql file I wanted to import.

In order to get rid of this problem you could just move the file to a place you know you have access to (with your current user) for sure. (eg. ~/Home_directory).

I hope I could help some lonely soul that was searching for the answer just like I was.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue and did this...

- Delete Migrations Folder
- Drop the _migrationhistory table
- Enable, Add and Update migration

I'm sure there's a much better way to solve this but, it worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

I changed permissions for the mysql-data-directory as well as the `<table>.frm` file.
If using as root user:

- chmod 600 mysql-data-directory chmod 600
- mysql-data-directory/tableOfData.frm

If using as non-root user:

- chmod 660 mysql-data-directory
- chmod 660 mysql-data-directory/tableOfData.frm

Answer (score 0):

This error, "General error: 1017 Can't find file", also happened on Windows with WAMP if the table doesn't exist.

Answer (score 0):

Try following things:

- repair whole database
- change permission to mysql:mysql
- restart mysql service

One of these will work.

Comment: Yes but i got this issue and restarting service worked for me. Most of us know how to do the above so it's just a hint.