# MySQL: ERROR 1017 (HY000): Can't find file when creating table

Tags: mysql

I searched for this error here but nothing really relates to my problem.

I'm trying to debug a script, which starts with

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS 'tablename' (...)
```

However both in the script and in the MySQL client on console I get this error:

ERROR 1017 (HY000): Can't find file: 'tablename' (errno: 2)

The strange thing is: The database is completely empty.

What I checked:

-The mysql Server is running as user 'mysql', the directory with the mysql databases and the files belong to the same user and have enough rights (read/write/execute).

-The user I use to log into the mysql client has the right to create tables.

In the mysql client I can even drop the empty database and create it again, but I still can't create a table.

EDIT: It somehow was a problem with the table name. I just added "Test" to end of the tablename, and then it worked, despite me dropping and creating the database several times. I assume that the table name was still somehow cached in mysql. The script ran on the same server before without problems, but as it was a temporary table, the table was deleted later.

EDIT2: Admin restarted the DB, this solved the problem without any changes to the original command.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/12108426/3181416

Comment: Thanks, but I checked the permissions, and I can't use mysqlcheck to repair the table, **because I don't have a table**

Comment: Try piscator's reply

Answer (score 1):

Don't use single quotes for a table name. Try this:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `tablename` (...)
```

Without backticks will work as well since tablename isn't a reserved keyword:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS tablename (...)
```

Check the rights for the datadir. Run:

```
mysql -uUSERNAME -p -e 'SHOW VARIABLES WHERE Variable_Name LIKE "%dir"'
```

And change the rights / ownership. For example the one shown in the link from the comments of your OP:

```
chown -R mysql:mysql datadir
```

Comment: Sorry, 'tablename' was just an example, I didn't want to post the whole table definition. I tried with the real tablename now, with and without single quotes, didn't change anything :(

Comment: No problem. Are you sure you've checked the right datadir for the permissions?

Comment: I got it.. Tablename was "tmpAvailableExamplePerWeek".. I changed it to "tmpAvailableExamplePerWeekTest", now it worked.. I guess mysql has it cached despite me dropping the whole database.. I can't restart the mysql server to check though..